# MySQL Date and time insert error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, date

I am trying to insert date and time to a table in MySQL db from a JSP page but ended with an error:

```
Severe:   java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect datetime value: '15/05/2015 14:00:00' for function str_to_date
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
```

**Date format** in JSP page `is dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM`
For ex, the date is 15/05/2015 and time is 14:00

How can I fix the problem or what is correct way of doing it?

the stored procedure:

```
 CREATE... PROCEDURE `Add(Id int,
 Date_In varchar(50),Out result int)
 BEGIN
 IF (select count(*) from myTable Where DATE_FORMAT(Datein,     '%d/%m/%Y')=DATE_FORMAT(Date_In, '%d/%m/%Y') and id=Id) < 1 then
BEGIN
INSERT INTO myTable (id, DateIn) 
VALUES (id,str_to_date(Date_In,'%d/%M/%Y %H:%i'));
set result=1;
END;
END if;
end

java code:
String date = request.getParameter("date");
String time = request.getParameter("time");
String dateTIme = date + " " + time + ":00";

and insert statement goes here.
```

Comment: What is your `DateIn` column type in database?Date or another type?

Comment: it is a datetime type

Comment: `str_to_date(Date_In,'%d/%M/%Y %H:%i')` change to `str_to_date(Date_In,'%d-%M-%Y %H:%i')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you change

```
VALUES (id,str_to_date(Date_In,'%d/%M/%Y %H:%i')
```

to

```
VALUES (id,str_to_date(Date_In,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'));
```

?
You are missing seconds as per the exception

Answer (score 0):

You have used `str_to_date(Date_In,'%d/%M/%Y %H:%i')`.

According to [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp), `%M` signifies that the month is being specified in the name format. In your case, you should change your format to `%d%m%Y`, or alter your input to `15/MAY/2015`.